# Questions dealing with cdf (cumulative distribution function) $F(x)=(k-\frac{1}{\lfloor x\rfloor})[x \ge 1],$

Tags: probability, cumulative-distribution-functions

Recall that the "floor" of a real number  $x$ , denoted  $\lfloor x \rfloor$ , is the largest integer  $\leq x$ .

$$F(x)=  \begin{cases} k-\frac{1}{\lfloor x\rfloor}, & x \ge 1,\\ 0, & x \lt 1,\end{cases}$$  is a cummulative distribution function (cdf) for some fixed number  k . Find: k. and P(X=4)

i am able to find k as it is cdf so as x->infinity, F(x)=1
but i am not able to find P(X=4) why P(X=4) will not be equal to 3/4?

Comment: @premez In the title, I was using Iverson bracket convention (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket), now widespread.

Comment: @JeanMarie i edited it in qus it is written P(X=4)

Comment: Are you conscious that the derivative $f$ of $F$ is made of smallest and smallest spikes meaning that it is a discrete distribution with $p(n+1)=1/n-1/(n+1)$ with $n=1,2,3...$?

Comment: @JeanMarie i am unable to follow you

Comment: @JeanMarie i know it is a jumping function for [1,2) it will be k-1/1 and for [2,3) it will be k-1/2 and so on..

Comment: I mean you are in a particular case where $F$ instead of being continuous, has a curve which is made of flat parts for $x \in [n,n+1)$ and "jumps" at integer values of $f$. Therefore you cannot say "I differentiate $F$ and I get $f$" (well you could do it in the framework of the so-called "distributions theory"). Therefore, you have to think in a different way : what makes these jumps at integer values of $x$ ... and what is the consequence for $f$...

Comment: @JeanMarie can you plz explain how to solve it, i am unable to follow your hints

Comment: If you are familar with jumps for a cdf, you must have been said that the intensity of the jump at $x=a$ is the correponding probability for $X$ to be equal to $a$. That's all : the $n$th jump has intensity $1/n-1/(n+1)=1/(n-n+1)$ therefore $p(X=2)=1/2, P(X=3)=1/6,P(X=4)=1/12$...

Comment: @JeanMarie thankyou so much  i got it  P(X=4)=F(4)−F(3)=3/4−2/3=1/12 .

Answer (score 1):

Here is my method to solve this problem:

$P(X <= 4) = P(X = 4) + P(X < 4)$ .... eq(1)

Therefore, $P(X = 4) = P(X <= 4) - P(X < 4)$

i.e.,$P(X = 4) = P(X <= 4) - P(X <= 3)$

$P(X = 4) = F(4) - F(3)$

$P(X = 4) = 1/4 - 1/3 = (1/12)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).